# remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed for

Tags: git, github

I use Git for Windows. I created SSH key and added it into the keys list of my GitHub settings according [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/). Now I try to use it, but I get the error:

```
$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': Andrey-Bushman
Password for 'https://Andrey-Bushman@github.com':
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Andrey-Bushman/sandbox.git/
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You should use username `git`.

Comment: can you write your `git remote -v` result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure, ssh keys are successfully created by executing the command:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
```

It should print
`"Hi Andrey-Bushman! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does notprovide shell access."`

If not, then refer to [SSH Access to Git](https://aggarwalarpit.wordpress.com/author/aggarwalarpit/).

Once done follow the steps below:

1. clone the repo using ssh protocol as:

   `git@github.com:<github-username>/<repo>.git`

   In your case:

   `git@github.com:Andrey-Bushman/<repo>.git`
2. Commit your changes to the repo.
3. Then, `git push origin <branch-name>`

   In your case:

   `git push origin master`

Comment: > If it prints "Hi Andrey-Bushman! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does notprovide shell access." Yes, it prints.

Comment: > git@github.com:Andrey-Bushman/<repo>.git Where I must to use it?

Comment: No, first you have to `clone` the repo using ssh and then push it using origin name.